# Analysis, series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to show that $a_n=\sqrt[n]4$ is convergent and then find the limiting value.
How can I formally show that an is convergent? To find the limiting value is it enough to use this line of reasoning:

$\sqrt[n]4=4^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and then $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow0$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$ so $\sqrt[n]4=4^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow1$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Use the squeeze theorem if you aready know that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1\;$ :

$$1\le\sqrt[n]4\le\sqrt[n]n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]4=1$$

Comment: Thank you it makes sense. But how can I show $a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: You can prove it by saying it's a monotonous decreasing succession and it has a finite limit ($1$), so it converges to $1$.

Comment: Nice thank you, now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

1) Bounded below:

$1=1^{1/n} \lt (4)^{1/n}$; $n \ge 1$.

2) Decreasing:

$4= 4^{1/n}4^{1/n}.....4^{1/n}$, $n$ factors.

$4=4^{1/(n+1)}4^{1/(n+1)}....4^{1/(n+1)}$, $n+1$ factors.

$a_n=4^{1/n} >1$, $a_{n+1}=4^{1/n+1} >1$;

Consider:

$(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})^n\cdot a_{n+1}=1$;

Since $a_{n+1}>1$ it follows $(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})^n<1$, and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} <1$, i.e. decreasing.

Bounded below and decreasing hence convergent.